Azure Maps SAS creation fails
I have to use the weather API from Azure MAPS with Shared access signature token authentication
I have followed the instructions from here:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-maps/azure-maps-authentication.md#create-sas-tokens
So the actions I've taken so far are the following :

I have created an Azure MAPs account along with  a user-assigned
managed identity in the same location as the Azure Maps account.
I have assigned role-based access control for the managed
identity to an Azure Maps data role at the account scope.
I have registered an APP and I have given it API permissions for Azure Maps along with the Azure Maps Data Reader role from Azure MAPs IAM

I can manually create the SAS token on the Azure Maps account relevant field and it works fine.
However, I need to create SAS tokens in my back-end solution programmatically.
So I followed the example form here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps-management/accounts/list-sas?view=rest-maps-management-2023-06-01&tabs=HTTP
and created the following Python code:
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.maps import AzureMapsManagementClient
import os
import datetime
"""
# PREREQUISITES
    pip install azure-identity
    pip install azure-mgmt-maps
# USAGE
    python account_list_sas.py

    Before run the sample, please set the values of the client ID, tenant ID and client secret
    of the AAD application as environment variables: AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_TENANT_ID,
    AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET. For more info about how to get the value, please see:
    https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal
"""
client_id = "fdxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "Nqxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
tenant_id = "92xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
subscription_id = "6fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
principal_id = "22xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID'] = tenant_id
os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'] = client_secret
os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"] = subscription_id
os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID'] = client_id
def format_time(time: datetime.datetime) -> str:
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'

def main():
    client = AzureMapsManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id=subscription_id,
    )
    time_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    response = client.accounts.list_sas(
        resource_group_name="my_group_name",
        account_name="my_account_name",
        maps_account_sas_parameters={
            "expiry": format_time(time_now + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)),
            "maxRatePerSecond": 500,
            "principalId": principal_id,
            "regions": ["westeurope"],
            "signingKey": "primaryKey",
            "start": format_time(time_now),
        },
    )
    print(response)


# x-ms-original-file: specification/maps/resource-manager/Microsoft.Maps/stable/2023-06-01/examples/AccountListSAS.json
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

However, I always get the error
Message: The client '70exxxxxxxxxxx' with object id '70exxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Maps/accounts/listSas/action' over scope '/subscriptions/6fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/my_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Maps/accounts/my_account_name' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

So the first question is where the code finds the above client 70exxxxxxxxxxx since I have put a different value in the client ID of the registered app.
I've checked many times the values for

client_id
client_secret
tenant_id
subscription_id
principal_id

and they are the correct ones.
Since I'm quite new to Azure, can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong here?
What is missing from the configuration point of view?
Thank you for your time.

Could you copy that client ID from error message '70exxxxxxxxxxx' and search it in Enterprise applications by removing filters to find application name?

@Sridevi I've checked and it's the object ID of the registered app.

Try assigning "Azure Maps Data Contributor" role to the registered application under Maps service

@Sridevi  I did it and have the same issue. I also created a new client secret just in case but the problem persisted.

Instead of DefaultAzureCredential(), make use of client secret credentials

I place the following
credential=ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenant_id,client_id=client_id,client_secret=client_secret)
but the error remains the same unfortunatelly.

I'm pretty sure you want to use the "Azure Maps Search and Render Data Reader" role. The other Data reader/contributor roles I believe are for the Azure Maps Creator platform where you would upload data to Azure Maps.

I have created an Azure Maps account along with a user-assigned managed identity in the same location as below:

Later, I assigned Azure Maps Data Contributor role to user managed identity under Maps account like this:

Now, I registered one Entra ID application and added both Azure Maps API permissions and Azure Maps Data Contributor role under Maps account:


Initially, I too got same error when I ran your code in my environment like this:
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.maps import AzureMapsManagementClient
import os
import datetime
"""
# PREREQUISITES
    pip install azure-identity
    pip install azure-mgmt-maps
# USAGE
    python account_list_sas.py

    Before run the sample, please set the values of the client ID, tenant ID and client secret
    of the AAD application as environment variables: AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_TENANT_ID,
    AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET. For more info about how to get the value, please see:
    https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal
"""
client_id = "fdxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "Nqxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
tenant_id = "92xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
subscription_id = "6fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
principal_id = "22xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID'] = tenant_id
os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'] = client_secret
os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"] = subscription_id
os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID'] = client_id
def format_time(time: datetime.datetime) -> str:
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'

def main():
    client = AzureMapsManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id=subscription_id,
    )
    time_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    response = client.accounts.list_sas(
        resource_group_name="my_group_name",
        account_name="my_account_name",
        maps_account_sas_parameters={
            "expiry": format_time(time_now + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)),
            "maxRatePerSecond": 500,
            "principalId": principal_id,
            "regions": ["westeurope"],
            "signingKey": "primaryKey",
            "start": format_time(time_now),
        },
    )
    print(response)


# x-ms-original-file: specification/maps/resource-manager/Microsoft.Maps/stable/2023-06-01/examples/AccountListSAS.json
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Response:

To resolve the error, make sure to assign "Contributor" role to Entra ID application under both Azure Maps account and user assigned managed identity as below:
Azure Maps account:

User Assigned Managed Identity:

When I ran below code after assigning "Contributor" role to Entra ID application, I got the response with account_sas_token successfully like this:
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.maps import AzureMapsManagementClient
import os
import datetime

client_id = "appId"
client_secret = "secret"
tenant_id = "tenantId"
subscription_id = "subId"
principal_id = "managedObjectId"

def format_time(time: datetime.datetime) -> str:
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'

def main():
    credential = ClientSecretCredential(
        tenant_id=tenant_id,
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret
    )
    
    client = AzureMapsManagementClient(
        credential=credential,
        subscription_id=subscription_id,
    )
    
    time_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    response = client.accounts.list_sas(
        resource_group_name="rgname",
        account_name="mapsname",
        maps_account_sas_parameters={
            "expiry": format_time(time_now + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)),
            "maxRatePerSecond": 500,
            "principalId": principal_id,
            "regions": ["eastus"],
            "signingKey": "primaryKey",
            "start": format_time(time_now),
        },
    )
    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Response:

Reference:
Azure Maps Authentication requires 'Contributor' role · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub
